# Using a feature receiver to add a directory to the web applications folder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature-activation, feature-receiver

Wondering if someone knows how to add a directory/folder to the web applications folder within IIS using a feature event receiver (FeatureActivated).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean an application directory or virtual host within IIS, or a folder within a SharePoint site collection?

Comment: application directory within iis...

Comment: What is the purpose of using an application directory, is it for a custom web application (repeatable process) or some other file serving needs? Seeing this is a web server configuration change, I would not be recommending it through an event receiver.

Comment: a third party control i am using needs a temp directory in the web apps virtual directory.....just trying to automate so i don't have to ask the client to do anything. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  In the Feature receiver i used the following code to get the virtual path to the webapplication and then create a directory.  Never know if someone else will use it :)

```
string path = webApp.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(SPUrlZone.Default).Path.ToString();

        try{
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Temp");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            // Get the local instance of the diagnostics service
            SPDiagnosticsService diagService = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
            // Log the event under the SharePoint Foundation, Web Part category
            SPDiagnosticsCategory diagCategory = diagService.Areas["SharePoint Foundation"].Categories["Web Parts"];
            // The exception message to write to the log
            string exceptionId = "Web Part Exception Unique ID: " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string exceptionMsg = exceptionId + " " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;

            // Log the event as unexpected
            diagService.WriteTrace(0, diagCategory, TraceSeverity.Unexpected, exceptionMsg);
        }
```